# Virtual Host: Access local and online

Tags: vhosts

I need some help, I have a vhosts test.com from my server and I already added it in my host file in my computer, but I also want to access the test.com (not in my server), is it possible to access them both? How is it possible?

This is what I added in my hosts file

```
   192.168.10.5 test.com
   192.168.10.5 www.test.com
```

Comment: If you add test.com in server then you will access that domain in your network computer ...

Comment: i can already access my test.com but my problem is i also want to access existing test.com online.

Comment: i already set my domain name as test.com, is there other way to do it?

Comment: set test.com only. then use www domain for accessing online domain.

Comment: ah.. so it means in my host, i will use 192.168.10.5 test.com only? so that in www.test.com i can access the online? i already uses www.test.com as an alias of it.